# cannot get custom object from intent in service

Tags: android, android-intent

I am creating a music player. When I send service info and playlist in custom object to MyService in intent, MyService ca not get it from intent and returns null

sending intent to Myservice:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyService.class);
                intent.putExtra("command", list.get(position));
                intent.putExtra("dataBase", serviceInfo);
                getActivity().startService(intent);`
```

trying to get service info in MyService from intent

```
serviceInfo = (SettingsAndPlaylist) intent.getSerializableExtra("dataBase");
            position = serviceInfo.getPosition();
            repeatController = serviceInfo.isRepeat();
            playList = serviceInfo.getPlayList();
```

object with settings and playlist is serealizable and not null in the sending intent

[player sources](https://github.com/Nickdnepr/diplomProject/commits/master)

Comment: what is the type of objects that List holds

Comment: Could it be that the intent is null, and not your 'dataBase' object?
 please check (and post) exception from logcat

Comment: You should include your source code for SettingsAndPlaylist in the question rather than use an external link: else, when your code on github changes, his question and the answers would be meaningless to a new reader (this is why I copied the relevant part of it in my answer). Or better, create a minimalistic test-case to exhibit your issue, and post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your serializable class reads:

```
public class SettingsAndPlaylist implements Serializable {
    private static List playList;
    private static int position;
    private static boolean repeat;
    private static boolean random;
```

Serialization works for an object instance fields, *not* static fields.
By the way, you should also declare a serialVersionUID.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html for details about both points.

Comment: There's your problem!

Comment: i have to declare a serialVersionUID in the SettingsAndPlaylist, right?

Comment: indeed, something like private static final long serialVersionUID = 8091360262568306407L; (the identifier should be unique, any modern IDE should display a warning and offer to generate an identifier)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what flags you return from `onStartCommand`, have you tried different flags, like [`START_REDELIVER_INTENT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_REDELIVER_INTENT)?

If your are using [`START_STICKY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) you need to be prepared for null intents.